# Apache NIFI execute stream processor is not sending flowfiles to its subsequent execute stream processor

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I created a generate flow file which creates a dummy random flow file which has a random value. It was connected to a ExecuteStreamCommand processor which runs a python function. The python function creates a simple text file.

```
    with open("C:\\path\\newfile.txt",'w+') as myfile:
        myfile.write("the process was sucessful")
        myfile.close()
```

after this it is connected to another ExecuteStreamCommand processor. Which contains a python program which just appends a new line to the text file.

```
    with open("C:\\path\\newfile.txt",'a+') as myfile:
        myfile.write("second line  was added")
        myfile.close()
```

after that again another ExecuteStreamCommand processor. Which contains a python program which just appends a new line to the text file.

```
    with open("C:\\path\\newfile.txt",'a+') as myfile:
        myfile.write("third line  was added")
        myfile.close()
```

The problem is the first executeStreamCommand processor is the only one getting executed and the flowfile(dummy one which is not being used in python script) is not being pushed to subsequent queues and then to the processors. How can i resolve this. I basically need to create a workflow rather than a dataflow.
[process flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BORLf.png)

i tried adding a=sys.stdin.readfile() and sys.stdout.write(a) in all the 3 execute stream processors but didnt change the outcome.

Comment: First `executeStreamCommand` processor execution is not working properly so it is not able to send FF to downstream. Please check around it.